# python csv print first 10 rows only

Tags: csv, awk

I am working with a large CSV file with a lot of rows and columns. I need only the first 5 columns but only if the value for column 1 of each row is 1. (Column 1 can only have value 0 or 1).

So far I can print out the first 5 columns but can't filter to only show when column 1 is equal to 1. My .awk file looks like:

```
BEGIN {FS = ","}
NR!=1 {print $1", " $2", " $3", "$4", "$5}
```

I have tried things like $1>1 but to no luck, the output is always every row, regardless if the first column of each row is a 0 or 1.

Comment: what commands did you used?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. So far every answer is interpreting your requirements differently from each other. It's not clear, for example if you want to output the first 10 rows that start with 1 or if you want to output the rows that start with 1 from the first 10 lines of input. Just show a good example to make it all clear.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your awk a bit:

```
BEGIN {FS = ","; OFS = ", "}
$1 == 1 {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; n++}
n == 10 {exit}
```